# How to create Lower Limit and Upper Limit in HSV color space?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, hsv

I was working with Color filtering using openCV in python. I came to this step where I have to create a lower and upper limit of Blue color.

```
lower_blue = np.array([35, 140, 60]) 
upper_blue = np.array([255, 255, 180])
```

So I want to know how to define a range of blue color?

Answer (score 2):

Hue is define from 0 to 360 degrees as follows where blue is at 240 degrees and ranges from about 210 to 270

[image]

However, in Python/OpenCV, hues are scaled to the range 0 to 180. So all hues from the chart are divided by 2. So blue would be at 120 and range from about 105 to 135. That would provide a starting point for blue. But not all blue shades have full saturation or value (brightness). So you need to give a spread for each of those as well with the high value at 255.

What I often do is convert the image to HSV and save it. The open it in some GUI based tool such as GIMP or Photoshop or use Python GUI to measure the actual range of blue shades. Then I add and subtract some further tolerance to the lower and upper values and test by viewing my threshold image. I keep adjusting until I like the looks of the threshold.